# R Function Writing (Additional Arguments ...), passing to another function

Tags: r, function

I am writing on functions for my package, and have trouble in passing additional arguments with the `...`
I have a "background" function, in the MRE from below I called it (`change_font()`), which takes e.g. in the example 2 arguments (`fontsize` and `font`).

Now I wrote a second function, called `test()`in the example, and would like it to have the option (with `...`) to pass aditional arguments that should be passed to `change_font()`.

#### Problem

It works with `change_font(...)` from inside `test()` as long as the `...` only contains arguments used in the change_font function. I tried converting `...` in a list and filter it for the arguments in the `change_font()` function which did not work.

Is there a convient way (inside the test function) to just select the arguments needed for change_font from the ... argument?

#### MRE

```r
change_font <- function(fontsize = 12, font = "Times New Roman") {
  print(paste("Font is set to:", font))
  print(paste("Fontsize is set to:", fontsize))
}

test <- function(a = "ba", ...) {
  # change_font(...)
  # Works when only useable parameters are passed
  #    - However Fails when non-arguments from change_font are passed, e.g. test2 = 42
  
  # DID notwork
  # print(typeof(...))
  # print(class(...))
  
  
  # Trying to filter unused additional args
  additional_args <- list(...)[c("font","fontsize")]
  print(additional_args)
  # Filtering works fine. List only contains desired arguments
  change_font(additional_args)



  # if (hasArg(fontsize)) fontsize <- additional_args[["fontsize"]]
  # print(hasArg(font))
  # if (hasArg(font)) font = additional_args[["font"]]
  # # Try 2
  # change_font(
  #   font = font,
  #   fontsize = fontsize
  #
  # )
}

change_font()
#> [1] "Font is set to: Times New Roman"
#> [1] "Fontsize is set to: 12"
test(font = "ABC", fontsize = 111)
#> $font
#> [1] "ABC"
#> 
#> $fontsize
#> [1] 111
#> 
#> [1] "Font is set to: Times New Roman"
#> [1] "Fontsize is set to: ABC" "Fontsize is set to: 111"
test(font = "ABC", fontsize = 111, test2 = 42)
#> $font
#> [1] "ABC"
#> 
#> $fontsize
#> [1] 111
#> 
#> [1] "Font is set to: Times New Roman"
#> [1] "Fontsize is set to: ABC" "Fontsize is set to: 111"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have dots as a parameter in `change_font` that are just ignored inside the body of the function.

Compare a minimal example where `change_fonts` doesn't have dots as a parameter:

```r
change_font <- function(fontsize = 12, font = "Times New Roman") {

  print(paste("Font is set to:", font))
  print(paste("Fontsize is set to:", fontsize))
}
 

test <- function(a = "ab", ...) {

  change_font(...)
}
```

This results in an error if we pass an unrecognised parameter to `test`:

```
test(fontsize = 14, color = "red")
#> Error in change_font(...): unused argument (color = "red")
```

But look what happens when we include dots as a parameter in `change_font`:

```r
change_font <- function(fontsize = 12, font = "Times New Roman", ...) {

  print(paste("Font is set to:", font))
  print(paste("Fontsize is set to:", fontsize))
}

test(fontsize = 14, color = "red")
#> [1] "Font is set to: Times New Roman"
#> [1] "Fontsize is set to: 14"
```

What's happening here is that in both cases `color = "red"` is being passed as a parameter to `change_font`, but in the second example, rather than getting the error that the `color` argument is unrecognised, it is interpreted as one of the "dots parameters", so doesn't trigger an error.

This is a very commonly used tactic in R.

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my MRE this is the solution. I dont know why (I cant seem to reproduce the error). However inside my package I get the following error, by basically doing the same thing (passing `...` and receiving `...` in both functions): ```format_flextable(ft=raw_table, table_caption = table_caption, ...)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context``` I also tried the following ` ...=...` did not solve it either

Comment: Ah - that's because `format_flextable` doesn't take dots. In your MRE, we were free to add dots to the function definition of `change_font`, but we can't do that with `format_flextable`. That situation is a bit more complex - you would need to get the appropriate arguments in a list and then `call("format_flextable", args)` . So just like you were doing in your own example, except `call(change_font, additional_args)` instead of `change_font(additional_args)`

Comment: Oh sorry, it gets confusing because of the MRE however I wanted to abbreviated it with a MRE because the functions in my package are quite long. To lift the confusion `format_flextable()` is a function I wrote, and I added the `...` argument. However the error stems from me being dumb. I did not call the surrounding function, from which format_flextable is called, but rather tried to exectued the call directly in console. Of course this way ... is unkown. Now it works fine. Thanks so much